# Pass props to another component using react redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following code

```
if (_get(this.state, 'showCheckoutSuccess') == false) {
            alert("Order Failed: Not Enough Credits");
            return <Redirect push to={{
                pathname: '/view-cart',
            }} />;
        }
```

what it does orginally is just show a popup after redirect. But I want to be able to pass the showCheckOutSuccess info to that component to  display a message on a line of the page.

I am not having any luck what I have tried doing was this:

```
if (_get(this.state, 'showCheckoutSuccess') == false) {
                return <Redirect push to={{
                    state: { showCheckoutSuccess: "false" }
                    pathname: '/view-cart',
                }} />;
            }
```

and then using `this.props.location.state.showCheckoutSuccess`

this results in an error when i normally navigate to the cart page and it says that showCheckoutSuccess is undefined.

I think its because the info was never passed to it but users should still be able to get to the cart page even if this error never comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You need redux or some other state manager (React Context will work too).

Or you can use the history hook.

```
history.push({
  pathname:"/view-cart",
  state:{
    showCheckoutSuccess: "false"
  }
});
```

and then access it like `props.location.state.showCheckoutSuccess`.

Comment: says " props is not defined" when i go to the cart page

Comment: did you pass  props in the CartPage function definition?